# How to handle large amounts of data to achieve good performance?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some files of size 1mb to 2mb (I will need one file at a time) which i want to load on my website using `fopen()` and then show the related information on website. I have to read these files every now and then to search inside the files and show the info:

So i wanted to know Which option is better concerning Performance,

1. Whether i should open file using `fopen()` and then use.
2. Whether i should convert the file data to array and then load and use.
3. Whether i should insert all the data into MySQL and then fetch and use.
4. Whether i should load/fetch info and then serialize it and then save it into a file and use it for all the future purpose use.

or are any other options available.

Data is something like this and around 30,000 lines:

```
1000,Asther,Asther Path,0,50,,70,5,2,,5,FFF,7,2,,24,,45,,{ "is a good girl" },{},{} 
1001,Sinkn,Sinkn Keth,0,50,,70,,7,34,6,FFF,7,2,65,3,,67,,{ "Like flower" },{},{}
```

Comment: Without a proper description of the data this is impossible to answer. But usually database is your best option, because that's just what they were made for.

Comment: Data is something like this and around ( 30,000) lines:

1000,Asther,Asther Path,0,50,,70,5,2,,5,FFF,7,2,,24,,45,,{ "is a good girl" },{},{}

1001,Sinkn,Sinkn Keth,0,50,,70,,7,34,6,0xFFFFFFFF,7,2,65,3,,67,,{ "Like flower" },{},{}

Comment: I would highly recommend putting that into a database. Is there a special reason why you are storing that in files?

Comment: Well, I was thinking to reduce some what load from the Database Engine so my other queries can take advantage and load faster.

Comment: Sounds like the wrong approach to me. If the DBMS is too slow, you either need to improve your queries, maybe add additional indexes, tweak the configuration of just give it better hardware to work with. ;) The DBMS is there to help you work with data...if it's unable to do it, something is wrong. And moving data to files is not the way to solve it, if you ask me.

Comment: No no, the DBMS is working fine. This question was actually pinching me every now and then, because at first i thought to load data using fopen() then i saw that file is taking quite a time to load and display information, So i thought to take Professional opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 1 file to load data from, file is easier to do than MySQL. Array definition in the file will be an even better option (save the time to parse / unserialize).

If you have quite a number of files, it will be slow to scan the directory and `fopen` the files one by one. It doesn't help much to turn files to array / serialized data. File operation plus directory scan is slower in PHP than in MySQL. MySQL will automatically index your data so it'll be better than PHP for any complex search. MySQL would be a better option in this case.

Comment: Yes, After Reading the reply i think i should go with MySQL. Thank you.